# How to pipe a go program's output in terminal to another program?

Tags: go, terminal, output, io-redirection

I want to run grep on the output produced by a go program. With other languages, I can easily do it. e.g.: java Test | grep world

Even redirecting the output to a file doesn't seem to work and the file created is empty and the terminal still prints the output.

```golang
package main
func main() {
  println("One")
  println("Hello")
}
```

Expected:

```sh
go build test.go
./test | grep 'el'
Hello
```

Actual:

```sh
go build test.go
./test | grep 'el'
One
Hello
```

Comment: Never use `println`. Use `fmt.Println` instead. `println` is there as a debugging tool for those developing the language.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake.

From println documentation:

> The println built-in function formats its arguments in an
>   implementation-specific way and writes the result to standard error.

So, it doesn't output on stdout. For printing to stdout, fmt.Println can be used instead.